# Dynamic calculation in Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a "Trader Stall Application" form and want the cost of the Trade Space to be calculated when the user enters the "Frontage Metre" value (eg 10mtrs) multiplied against a static figure (eg $15/mt) = $150 to show on the form as the user completes this.

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms doesn't make automatic calculations to be displayed to the user that is filling the form.

You could use Google Apps Script and the onFormSubmit trigger to do that calculation and send it through email o save in a document, like a spreadsheet, document (word processing file), presentation.

Another alternative is to use the Apps Script HTML Service to create your own web form but this requires to know about programming and HTML/CSS/JavaScript.